# Comma separated list from multiple sql columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string-aggregation

Using SQL Server 2012, I have a table containing multiple checkbox fields where the values are 1 or 0, obviously.  I need to pull any of these fields where any of these values are 1.

So:

```
ID      Building            Heavy         Municipal       Industry
101        1                   1              0               1
```

Results:

```
ID               Type
101              Building, Heavy, Industry
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

assuming the number columns are few can just use IIF 2012+ otherwise case

Substring to determine starting position and ending.

```
select ID, 
    SUBSTRING(
    IIF(Building=1,', Building','') + 
            IIF(Heavy=1,', Heavy','') + 
            IIF(Municipal=1,', Municipal','') + 
            IIF(Industry=1,', Industry','')
            ,3,100)   -- substring to start from pos 3 and ends at position 100 depends on the desired length
           Type
from table
```

Comment: I think that the concatenation must be improved, otherwise you may end up with: `BuildingHeavyMunicipalIndustry` or Am I wrong? Ooh +1 for the simple idea though

Comment: there is an extra comma.. i will improve this cheers

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is, 
Step 1. Unpivot the table

```
SELECT ID, Sub, SubVal
INTO #t2
FROM (SELECT * FROM #t)t
UNPIVOT
(
    SubVal FOR Sub IN (Building,Heavy, Muncipal, Industry)
) as un
```

[image]

Step 2: Use for FOR XML PATH,

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID,
    STUFF((
        SELECT ' , ' + t2.Sub  
        FROM #t2 t2
        WHERE SubVal = 1
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2, '')   AS Type
FROM #t2 ct
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `CASE` statement like so:

```
create table test (
    id int,
    building int,
    heavy int,
    municipal int,
    industry int
);
insert into test values (101, 1, 1, 0, 1);

with data as (
    select id,
        case when building = 1 then 'Building,' else '' end +
        case when heavy = 1 then 'Heavy,' else '' end +
        case when municipal = 1 then 'Municipal,' else '' end +
        case when industry = 1 then 'Industry,' else '' end as fld
    from test
)
select id, left(fld, len(fld)-1) as fld from data;
```

Example: http://rextester.com/CKGES46149

Result:

```
id  fld
101 Building,Heavy,Industry
```

**If a space after comma is needed, add a slight modification like so:**

```
with data as (
    select id,
        rtrim(
        case when building = 1 then 'Building, ' else '' end +
        case when heavy = 1 then 'Heavy, ' else '' end +
        case when municipal = 1 then 'Municipal, ' else '' end +
        case when industry = 1 then 'Industry, ' else '' end
        ) as fld
    from test
)
select id, left(fld, len(fld)-1) as fld from data;
```

Result:

```
id  fld
101 Building, Heavy, Industry
```

Example: http://rextester.com/OJNEQ98420